# telnet expect module like sharpssh

Tags: c#, telnet, expect

I am using sharpssh with expect and working perfectly. Is there any library for telnet(with expect) so that i can access my routers, execute commands and receive the result.

I have tried searching on net but wasnt successful. Pls guide me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project:

http://telnetexpect.codeplex.com/

"A library providing Telnet connectivity, ANSI terminal support, and finally UNIX Expect-like scripting."

Answer (score -1):

telnet is just opening a socket on an IP/port

Comment: So any guidance on how can i use it to connect on my routers and then getting back the result of the commands ?